# weird error with undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass and undefined method `strptime' for nil:NilClass RoR 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, null

Hi I'm trying to read csv file, my code is this:

```
CSV.foreach(path, {:col_sep => @seperator}) do |row|
    #CSV.foreach(File.basename(path), {:col_sep => @seperator}) do |row|
        r = Route.new
        r.contact_id = contact_id
        r.name = row[0]
        r.number_range = row[1]
        r.rate = row[3].gsub(",", ".").to_f
        r.valid_from = DateTime.strptime(row[5], @time_format) 
        r.currency = @currency
        r.save
    end
```

And I'm having a problem in this lines:

```
        r.rate = row[3].gsub(",", ".").to_f
        r.valid_from = DateTime.strptime(row[5], @time_format)
```

I get the errors: `undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass` and

```
undefined method `strptime' for nil:NilClass
```

But I'm completely sure that row[3] and row[5] aren't nil, any idea about why is it happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .gsub() is a String method, so it will only work when the row[3] value is a string.  It seems that some of your rows are nil. To avoid this you could add a simple checker for nil values

```
r.rate = row[3].gsub(",",".").to_f if row[3].nil?
```

Again the same error for the next line.  so you can change it to:

```
r.valid_from = DateTime.strptime(row[5], @time_format) if row[5].nil?
```

You say you are sure that the values are not nil, but that's exactly what the error is saying. It only takes 1 line with a nil value to break the entire script.

You're also hardcoding the rows 3 and 5. Perhaps you mean different rows? Try testing to make sure that row is equating to exactly what you think it is in IRB. Can you show us what row[3] and row[5] equal?

Comment: I mean rows 3 and 5. I tried to add this to the code: Rail.logger.info row[3](and also for 5) but it shows nothing

Comment: and with if nil != row[3] is not complaining, but now I'm not sure about if it is reading at I supposed

Comment: `r.rate = row[3].gsub(",",".").to_f unless row[3].nil?` and `r.valid_from = DateTime.strptime(row[5], @time_format) if row[5].nil?` look much better and is more readable

Comment: use the @ before the name of the user, it will notice him in his indox: @joofsh ;-)